# Modify value in HashMap while immutably borrowing the whole HashMap

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to learn Rust by using it in a project of mine.
However, I've been struggling with the borrow checker quite a bit in some code which has a very similar form to the following:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::vec::Vec;

struct MyStruct<'a> {
    value: i32,
    substructs: Option<Vec<Pin<&'a MyStruct<'a>>>>,
}

struct Toplevel<'a> {
    my_structs: HashMap<String, Pin<Box<MyStruct<'a>>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut toplevel = Toplevel {
        my_structs: HashMap::new(),
    };

    // First pass: add the elements to the HashMap
    toplevel.my_structs.insert(
        "abc".into(),
        Pin::new(Box::new(MyStruct {
            value: 0,
            substructs: None,
        })),
    );
    toplevel.my_structs.insert(
        "def".into(),
        Pin::new(Box::new(MyStruct {
            value: 5,
            substructs: None,
        })),
    );
    toplevel.my_structs.insert(
        "ghi".into(),
        Pin::new(Box::new(MyStruct {
            value: -7,
            substructs: None,
        })),
    );

    // Second pass: for each MyStruct, add substructs
    let subs = vec![
        toplevel.my_structs.get("abc").unwrap().as_ref(),
        toplevel.my_structs.get("def").unwrap().as_ref(),
        toplevel.my_structs.get("ghi").unwrap().as_ref(),
    ];
    toplevel.my_structs.get_mut("abc").unwrap().substructs = Some(subs);
}
```

When compiling, I get the following message:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `toplevel.my_structs` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:48:5
   |
44 |         toplevel.my_structs.get("abc").unwrap().as_ref(),
   |         ------------------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
48 |     toplevel.my_structs.get_mut("abc").unwrap().substructs = Some(subs);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------------------
   |     |
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
   |     immutable borrow later used here
```

I think I understand why this happens: `toplevel.my_structs.get_mut(...)` borrows `toplevel.my_structs` as mutable. However, in the same block, `toplevel.my_structs.get(...)` also borrows `toplevel.my_structs` (though this time as immutable).

I also see how this would indeed be a problem if the function which borrows `&mut toplevel.my_structs`, say, added a new key.

However, all that is done here in the `&mut toplevel.my_structs` borrow is modify the value corresponding to a specific key, which shouldn't change memory layout (and that's guaranteed, thanks to `Pin`). Right?

Is there a way to communicate this to the compiler, so that I can compile this code? This appears to be somewhat similar to what motivates the `hashmap::Entry` API, but I need to be able to access other keys as well, not only the one I want to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current problem is about conflicting mutable and immutable borrows, but there's a deeper problem here. This data structure *cannot* work for what you're trying to do:

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    value: i32,
    substructs: Option<Vec<Pin<&'a MyStruct<'a>>>>,
}

struct Toplevel<'a> {
    my_structs: HashMap<String, Pin<Box<MyStruct<'a>>>>,
}
```

Any time a type has a lifetime **parameter,** that lifetime necessarily outlives (or lives exactly as long as) the values of that type. A container `Toplevel<'a>` which contains references `&'a MyStruct` must refer to `MyStruct`s **which were created before the `Toplevel`** — unless you're using special tools like [an arena allocator](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/2.0.1/typed_arena/index.html).

(It's possible to straightforwardly build a tree of references, but they must be constructed leaves first and not using a recursive algorithm; this is usually impractical for dynamic input data.)

In general, references are not really suitable for *creating data structures;* rather they're for ***temporarily** “borrowing” parts of data structures.*

In your case, if you want to have a collection of all the `MyStructs` and also be able to add connections between them *after* they are created, you need **both shared ownership and interior mutability:**

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct MyStruct {
    value: i32,
    substructs: Option<Vec<Rc<RefCell<MyStruct>>>>,
}

struct Toplevel {
    my_structs: HashMap<String, Rc<RefCell<MyStruct>>>,
}
```

The shared ownership via `Rc` allows both `Toplevel` and any number of `MyStruct`s to refer to other `MyStruct`s. The interior mutability via `RefCell` allows the `MyStruct`'s `substructs` field to be modified even while it's being referred to from other elements of the overall data structure.

Given these definitions, you can write the code that you wanted:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut toplevel = Toplevel {
        my_structs: HashMap::new(),
    };

    // First pass: add the elements to the HashMap
    toplevel.my_structs.insert(
        "abc".into(),
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(MyStruct {
            value: 0,
            substructs: None,
        })),
    );
    toplevel.my_structs.insert(
        "def".into(),
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(MyStruct {
            value: 5,
            substructs: None,
        })),
    );
    toplevel.my_structs.insert(
        "ghi".into(),
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(MyStruct {
            value: -7,
            substructs: None,
        })),
    );

    // Second pass: for each MyStruct, add substructs
    let subs = vec![
        toplevel.my_structs["abc"].clone(),
        toplevel.my_structs["def"].clone(),
        toplevel.my_structs["ghi"].clone(),
    ];
    toplevel.my_structs["abc"].borrow_mut().substructs = Some(subs);
}
```

Note that because you're having `"abc"` refer to itself, this creates a reference cycle, which will not be freed when the `Toplevel` is dropped. To fix this, you can `impl Drop for Toplevel` and explicitly remove all the `substructs` references.

---

Another option, arguably more 'Rusty' is to *just use indices for cross-references*. This has several pros and cons:

- Adds the cost of additional hash lookups.
- Removes the cost of reference counting and interior mutability.
- Can have “dangling references”: a key could be removed from the map, invalidating the references to it.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct MyStruct {
    value: i32,
    substructs: Option<Vec<String>>,
}

struct Toplevel {
    my_structs: HashMap<String, MyStruct>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut toplevel = Toplevel {
        my_structs: HashMap::new(),
    };

    // First pass: add the elements to the HashMap
    toplevel.my_structs.insert(
        "abc".into(),
        MyStruct {
            value: 0,
            substructs: None,
        },
    );
    toplevel.my_structs.insert(
        "def".into(),
        MyStruct {
            value: 5,
            substructs: None,
        },
    );
    toplevel.my_structs.insert(
        "ghi".into(),
        MyStruct {
            value: -7,
            substructs: None,
        },
    );

    // Second pass: for each MyStruct, add substructs
    toplevel.my_structs.get_mut("abc").unwrap().substructs =
        Some(vec!["abc".into(), "def".into(), "ghi".into()]);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now; thanks! I actually considered the "just using the indices" method before, but rejected it largely due to your first&third point, and the fact that it would mean more code when I used the data structures (compared to just references). Just a question; is using `Rc<RefCell<_>>` really the only way to solve this while still using "references?" It seems a bit unecessary to use reference counting for this. Is there some reference page where I could check out possible alternatives?

Comment: Also, thank you very much for the warning regarding circular references. I'd definitely have missed that.

Comment: @dccsillag Reference counting is the only _safe_ option available _in the standard library_ for an object to be reachable via multiple paths without the forced temporary-ness of references. As you noted in your question, you can use raw pointers to avoid the reference counting, but then it's on you to make sure the objects are not actually deallocated or moved.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are attempting to modify a value referenced in the vector as immutable, which is not allowed. You could store mutable references in the vector instead, and mutate them directly, like this:

```rust
let subs = vec![
    toplevel.my_structs.get_mut("abc").unwrap(),
    toplevel.my_structs.get_mut("def").unwrap(),
    toplevel.my_structs.get_mut("ghi").unwrap(),
];
(*subs[0]).substructs = Some(subs.clone());
```

However, it's easier (although more expensive) to store clones of the structs instead of references:

```rust
let subs = vec![
    toplevel.my_structs.get("abc").unwrap().clone(),
    toplevel.my_structs.get("def").unwrap().clone(),
    toplevel.my_structs.get("ghi").unwrap().clone(),
];
(*toplevel.my_structs.get_mut("abc").unwrap()).substructs = Some(subs);
```

Comment: Am I really? They way I see it, my code would be exchanging the whole `Option<Vec<_>>` with another `Option<Vec<_>>`, and since the element types are references (which are not owned), this shouldn't invalidate any memory, and the compiler should be aware of that.

Comment: Also, I'll only know how to fill in the values in the second pass via input which gives me the keys in the hashmap I should look for. So I can't store things in an array/vec, as you proposed. And while cloning would really make things easier, I expect this will be quite memory intensive, so I really want to have references work.

Comment: When calling `get_mut`, you are using a mutable reference to the whole hashmap, not just the specific values in it that you want to change. The danger is that you could change the value of an immutable reference in your vector (which you are doing). When borrowing something as immutable (as hashmap.get does), you need to be able to rely on the value it's referencing never changing.

Comment: I think you meant "in your hashmap." (And it kinda needs to be a HashMap, not a vector, since I want fast access given the key). But yeah, I see it, thanks. Any pointers (excuse the pun :P) on how I could borrow only one member of the hashmap as mutable (without borrowing the hashmap as mutable as well)?

Comment: Just an update: turns out that pointer pun was actually quite good, since this can be easily solved with pointers and an unsafe block. But I'd rather not do this, so that I have some guarantee that I'm not messing things up (especially after future refactors).